# File descriptor leak example?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, file-descriptor, memory-leak-detector

Is there any good example do demonstrate file descriptor leak in Android? I read somewhere that it occurs if we don't close the streams for example `FileInputStream` or `FileOutputStream` but I could not find any good reference example which demonstrates it.

Please share some blog/code snippet. thank you!

Comment: Just open a bunch of files or ports without closing? After a few thousand windows stops giving them. Similar in other OSes.

Comment: @Ordous, thank you for your quick reply. Could you please post a working code snippet of it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because Dalvik's *FileInputStream* will [close itself when it is garbage collected](http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/libcore.git;a=blob;f=luni/src/main/java/java/io/FileInputStream.java;h=7944ef15642957bdf75748017d7619a961efb6f3;hb=HEAD#l135) (this is also true for OpenJDK/Oracle) it is less common than you'd think to actually leak file descriptors. Of course, the file descriptors will be "leaked" until the GC runs so depending on your program it could take a while before they are reclaimed.

To accomplish a more permanent leak you will have to prevent the stream from being garbage collected by keeping a reference to it somewhere in memory.

Here's a short example that loads a properties file every 1 second and keeps track of every time it has changed:

```
public class StreamLeak {

    /**
     * A revision of the properties.
     */
    public static class Revision {

        final ZonedDateTime time = ZonedDateTime.now();
        final PropertiesFile file;

        Revision(PropertiesFile file) {
            this.file = file;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Container for {@link Properties} that implements lazy loading.
     */
    public static class PropertiesFile {

        private final InputStream stream;
        private Properties properties;

        PropertiesFile(InputStream stream) {
            this.stream = stream;
        }

        Properties getProperties() {
            if(this.properties == null) {
                properties = new Properties();
                try {
                    properties.load(stream);
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return properties;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if(o instanceof PropertiesFile) {
                return ((PropertiesFile)o).getProperties().equals(getProperties());
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        URL url = new URL(args[0]);
        LinkedList<Revision> revisions = new LinkedList<>();
        // Loop indefinitely
        while(true) {
            // Load the file
            PropertiesFile pf = new PropertiesFile(url.openStream());
            // See if the file has changed
            if(revisions.isEmpty() || !revisions.getLast().file.equals(pf)) {
                // Store the new revision
                revisions.add(new Revision(pf));
                System.out.println(url.toString() + " has changed, total revisions: " + revisions.size());
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Because of the lazy loading we keep the *InputStream* in the *PropertiesFile* which will be kept whenever we create a new *Revision* and since we never close the stream we will be leaking file descriptors here.

Now, these open file descriptors will be closed by the OS when the program terminates, but as long as the program is running it will continue to leak file descriptors as can be seen by using [*lsof*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof):

```
$ lsof | grep pf.properties | head -n 3
java    6938   raniz   48r      REG    252,0    0    262694 /tmp/pf.properties
java    6938   raniz   49r      REG    252,0    0    262694 /tmp/pf.properties
java    6938   raniz   50r      REG    252,0    0    262694 /tmp/pf.properties
$ lsof | grep pf.properties | wc -l    
431
```

And if we force the GC to run we can see that most of these are returned:

```
$ jcmd 6938 GC.run
6938:
Command executed successfully
$ lsof | grep pf.properties | wc -l
2
```

The remaining two descriptors are the ones stored in the *Revision*s.

I ran this on my Ubuntu machine but the output would look similar if run on Android.

Answer (score -1):

```
InputStream in;
try {
    in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

    // Do your stuff with the input stream
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle your exception
} finally {
    // Close the stream here
    if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to close stream: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to close your file descriptor in the `finally` block.  Whether you finish successfully or an exception occurs, the file descriptor will be properly closed.

Now, if you're looking for something to demonstrate how to NOT do this properly, just wrap this code in a `while(1)` loop, comment out the `in.close()` line, and put a `break;` in your catch block so that when it blows up you'll break out of your infinite loop.

Comment: 1) This question is called "File descriptor leak example", not "how do I close streams properly". You are not even doing that the best way. 2) *just wrap this code in a while(1) loop* does not qualify as a "leak" (as in "accidental permanent loss of resource") 3) There is a pretty good chance, that stack trace creation will be followed by a GC pass, which will quickly finalize most of "leaked" streams.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I didn't understand your question.  However, considering you've had this question up for a month, with a bounty, and no one has answered it, I'm probably not the only one who doesn't understand what you're asking for.  Good luck to you.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> InputStream in;
>
> try {
>
>     in = new FileInputStream(new File("abc");
>
>
>     in.read(); // Do some stuff with open fileinputstream
>     // If an exception is generated, inputstream object will not be closed
>     // as the next statement will not be executed, instead jumping to 
>     // the catch block. this will cause a leak of the fd assigned to file 
>     // "abc" while opening it
>     in.close()' 
>   } catch (Exception e) {
>
>     // Handle your exception
>
>   }
> ```