# context.getExternalFilesDirs(null) returns a null element even when sd card is mounted

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdcard, sd-card

The following code is run in latest android version. A 32GB external SD card is mounted. The intent is to fetch data from SD card.

```
File[] externalFilesDirs = context.getExternalFilesDirs(null);
```

Sometimes `externalFilesDirs[1]` would return `null` which should give the path of the SD card storage. 
This is inconsistent issue. The issue occurs sometimes within minutes of opening the app and sometimes after hours of usage.
Once the `externalFilesDirs[1]` value starts coming `null`, It would always give `null` until the SD card is ejected and mounted back again.

The javadoc of `getExternalFilesDirs(String type)` states that:

```
* @return the absolute paths to application-specific directories. Some
* individual paths may be {@code null} if that shared storage is
* not currently available.
```

Does anyone have any idea about the root cause and how can it be resolved?

Comment: It may be locked by another process for reading/writing. Or it could be one of your own locks. Is it possible to leak file handles in Java?

Comment: I'm not sure Ivan

Comment: https://sdgsystems.com/blog/android-memory-and-file-descriptor-leaks-diagnosis-and-debugging-sdg-blog

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237918/file-descriptor-leak-example